# Determine Week number from a date(Month) using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I will like an assistance to get the determine if a particular date in a week falls into week1, week2 week3, or week 5 of that month. This code below returns 0-7 starting from mondaythrough saturday, but that is not what i wanted, rather i want to be able to determine e.g today is 19/09/2016, which falls into week3 of this Month. I need assistance on this please.

```
function getWeekday($date){
return date('w',strtotime($date));
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All you need is

```
ceil(date('d')/7);
```

So your function will look like

```
function getWeekday($date){
  return ceil(date('d',strtotime($date))/7);
}
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/644450)**

Even though requirement is a little strange. *Week of the month* is not a well defined thing but according to your comments on various answers all you need is to see week 1 if the date is within 1st 7 days of the month. 2 for next 7, 3 for next 7, 4 for next 7 and 5 for the leftovers.

**Output**

```
D   W
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   1
6   1
7   1
8   2
9   2
10  2
11  2
12  2
13  2
14  2
15  3
16  3
17  3
18  3
19  3
20  3
21  3
22  4
23  4
24  4
25  4
26  4
27  4
28  4
29  5
30  5
31  5
```

---

**Old answer**

Simple! you need a capital `W`, not a lowercase one.

> **W**
>
> ISO-8601 week number of year, weeks starting on Monday (added in PHP 4.1.0)

```
return date('W',strtotime($date));
```

The lowercase one - which you are using - is

> Numeric representation of the day of the week

**[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)**

Comment: thanks, but that is not what i wanted. Your response will give me week38, instead of week3. What i wanted is to take a month, and determine if that day falls into week1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 of that MONTH ONLY.

Comment: And which will be the starting point for *week of the month* ? Date 1st?

Comment: First day or first date? That's the question. When does the week start, can it start on a tuesdday, wednesday etc?

Comment: first date ie on 1st of each month

Comment: @Hankey, this answwer solves my question. Thanks ALL

Comment: Generally I recommend using the DateTime class, but for a simple and one-shot function like this the old `date()` and `strtotime()` functions work just fine. Glad you got your answer, @Dave

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
 echo date('W', strtotime($date)) - date('W', strtotime("first day of this month")) + 1;
```

Comment: let me try and get back

Comment: This is not a good way to go about it, I'm afraid. Not only because you're using the old functions for date manipulation, but also because this adds a lot of unnecessary complexity and manual calculations. See my answer for a cleaner and easier way to do it.

Comment: @ChristianF is this better ? echo  date('W', strtotime($date)) - date('W', strtotime("first day of this month")) + 1;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123673/discussion-between-christianf-and-mehravish-temkar).

Answer (score 1):

This is quite trivial with DateTime objects, or rather DateTimeImmutable.

```
// Immutable so we don't need to clone the object.
$date = new DateTimeImmutable ($date, $dtz);

// We need to find out which week number the month starts at.
$start = $date->modify ("first day of this month");

// The first week - the current week + 1 == The week in the month.
$monthWeek = $date->format ("W") - $start->format ("W") + 1;
```

That's all there is to it.

Comment: what variable is $dtz pls?

Comment: That is the DateTimeZone object. Please see the manual for DateTime for more information.
http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: it is throwing error of 1. Undefined variable: dtz. 2  Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object.3. Undefined $date. pls what am i doing wrong from your code?

Comment: You need to define the $dtz variable, with the correct timezone information. As per the manual. It's the __construct() method for the DateTime class you want to start on, btw.  http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

Comment: Also, just noticed that I used the wrong method in the second line. Changed it just now from `format()` to `modify()`, sorry about that.

Comment: Ok so today is 4th week of this month?

Comment: Nope its not. According to your own numerous comments, Date 19th should fall on the 3rd week not 4th week

Comment: @HankyPanky: if it is so, how do i achieve that? That's all I wanted pls

Comment: @Dave: You need to sit down and figure out exactly what you want, and why. My answer calculates weeks as you see them on the calender. While HankyPanky's by how many 7-day periods have passed, regardless of whether the "week" starts on a monday, saturday, or anything else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123676/discussion-between-christianf-and-hanky-panky).